# Align Texture to Edge Line

Tags: procedural, texture-coordinates

Is there any way to align the texture waves between the two selected edge lines with nodes?

[image]

Comment: If you don't succeed with the Generated output, you could easily do it with the UV output (if you choose Unwrap > Follow Active Quads for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the *Texture Coordinate UV* output instead of *Generated*, and unwrap your object with the *Follow Active Quads* method, it should work